# robots.txt Disallow: /checkout/ still myweb.com/checkout/cart/ Google still crawls

Tags: magento2, robots.txt

> robots.txt

```
Disallow: /checkout/
```

still, `myweb.com/checkout/cart/` Google still crawls,
I have set robots from admin.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `User-agent` to your robots file?

Can you see your file when accessed directly {your_domain}/robots.txt?

Also don't forget to flush cache after you have updated this settings.

To verify that you file works correctly you can use google tool: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961

Comment: Thank You but as mentioned here - https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-robots-txt-magento-2.html, configure robots.txt in Magento 2 but still {your_domain}/checkout/cart/ is crawl giving the error duplicate meta descriptoin